# Android change background color of popup menu

Tags: android, background, styles, popupmenu

I don't understand why is so painful to change a color for an android app.
I tried several ways to change the background color of the popup menu in my action bar with no success.

I'm using a AppTheme.NoActionBar to style, obviously, the action bar.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_return_dark</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/color4</item>
</style>
```

Following the examples that I found, there was this explanation that you need to insert in your custom style (in my case **AppTheme.NoActionBar**) a custom **popupMenuStyle** in order to custom the **popupBackground**, which changes the background color of popup menu.
It doesn't work.

[image]

What can I do to change the background color of popup menu?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh tried and gives this message: "Error:(2688, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupBackground'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the Options Menu in Android, changing themes and styles won't help. You have to initialise LayoutInflater Factory Class.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
   getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
   AttributeSet attrs) {
   if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
   try {
   LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
   final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
   new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

   view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_color);

   ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.your_color);
   }
   });
   return view;
   } catch (InflateException e) {
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   }
   }
   return null;
   }
   });
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

Comment: I'm inflating the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu method. The items are nested in the xml file. I'm not sure where to use OverflowMenu style in order to work. Could you please help me?

Comment: It doesn't have sense to just declare the above code in styles.xml and it doesn't work.  Where I should be using OverflowMenu, elsewhere except styles.xml?

Comment: Pardon me, I misunderstood the question for Overflow menu. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Don't worry. I found examples like this one using PopupMenu. My issue is that I'm using a nested list of items in menu.xml file. Inside onCreateOptionsMenu I inflate the menu and that's all. When I click the "parent" item, it opens a list of "child" items (white background color + white text color).

Comment: Why not change the color of text then instead of background?

Comment: Well I tried the same way I tried with the background, that's why I ended up with the decision of changing the background. In the same activity I'm using a navigation drawer and if I change the color for itemBackground that is declared in the style used in activity, it will change the color for the items from navigation drawer and not the overflown menu. :( It's really weird.

Comment: I added an image with the actual overflown menu. Since there is no solution for this kind of situation, I think I will probably start from scratch with something else.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Isn't Popup menu different from Options menu since you have initialised OnCreateOptionsMenu? I think you meant Options Menu when saying Popup menu.

Comment: Yes, that's right! I managed to fix the issue by declaring android:itemBackground and android:textColor in the style used by the activity. But your example is better than what I was expecting. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still wondering is there is a better solution to this problem, here's the explanation and answer.

Since, the question clearly mentions using NoActionBar theme for app, setting popupMenu directly to AppTheme will not work.

Instead you need to apply that theme manually to your toolbar in xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenu" />
```

and in your styles.xml file

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/popup_color</item>
</style>
```